# Why is it possible to subtract Date objects in javascript? Is there any form of operator overloading?

Tags: javascript, date, overloading, operator-keyword

Why is the below code actually working?

**Code**

```
var firstDate = new Date();

// some time passing here

var secondDate = new Date();

// Difference seems to contain difference in miliseconds. 

var difference = secondDate - firstDate;
```

What I get is, I believe, an equivalent to `secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime()`. The only question is, how can this conversion to number of milliseconds happen in background? Is this some sort of operator-overloading?

Comment: you can give (almost) any object a custom valueOf() and/or toString() method to enable the same sort of thing. Do realize that JS Date()s are just Numbers with some fancy prototype methods for easier human reading and mathematical manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator `-` converts the operands to numbers (check for example `"12"-3`). The date object defines a numeric conversion `.valueOf()` that returns the number of milliseconds.

See also for example `+(new Date)`.